# How to Wrap up a different types in a struct with void pointers

Tags: c, struct, casting, void-pointers, dereference

I had a plan earlier tonight, and now it's turning into a total mess.....I think I'm missing some fundamental concept.

Here's the idea:
I have to send some stuff over uart that looks like this (for example):

`rpmL.txt="10"`

`vbatt.txt="20.4"`

`info.txt="Low Temperature"`

`battIcon.pic='8'`

Simple enough, right?

Now, I have a bunch of different things that all have that same sort of format, but the only things that change are:

`rpmL, vbatt, etc.`

`txt` (this can be `txt` or `pic`)

`10, 20.4, Low Temperature, 8` (this can be an int or a float or a string or an enumeration...You'll see the enum below )

So, my idea was, just make a typedef'd struct that has all these things that can change in it, and then make another struct that holds a bunch of those typedef'd 'things'.

anyway, here's the code, and i just want to increment things in different ways depending on it's type:

```
screen.h

typedef enum _ScreenType{
    T_INT,
    T_FLOAT,
    T_CHAR,
    T_TEMP_ICON,
    T_BATT_ICON
} ScreenType;

typedef enum _tempIcon{
  TEMP_LOW = 0,
  TEMP_MED,
  TEMP_HIGH,
  //Add More Elements Up Here
  TEMP_MAX_ELEMENTS
}TempIcon;

typedef enum _battIcon{
  BATT_ZERO = 0,
  BATT_TWENTY_FIVE,
  BATT_FIFTY,
  BATT_SEVENTY_FIVE,
  BATT_FULL,
  //Add More Elements Up Here
  BATT_MAX_ELEMENTS
}BattIcon;

// Jam everything together so we can just pass the memeber of the following struct to the LCD TX function
typedef struct _packedStringVars{
  ScreenType ScreenType;  // I think I need this to achieve some crude polymorphism later on...
  void* var;  //I think I should do this because this can be a float, int or char*...
  char* label;  //This is always a string...nothing special about this.
}packedStringVars;

typedef struct{
  packedStringVars temp;
  packedStringVars wattage;
  packedStringVars battPercent;
  packedStringVars rpmL;
  packedStringVars rpmR;
  packedStringVars vbat;
  packedStringVars tempIcon;
  packedStringVars battIcon;
}mainScreenVariables;
```

and here's the source:

```
screen.c

#include "screen.h"
#include ..........Everything Else that You Would Expect.......

//This is where I'm trying to 'initialize' the values...I was doing *(int*) and *(float*), etc., but that went nowhere...
mainScreenVariables screenData = {
  .temp        = {T_INT,0,"temp"},
  .wattage     = {T_INT,0,"watts"},
  .rpmL        = {T_INT,0,"rpmL"},
  .rpmR        = {T_INT,0,"rpmR"},
  .vbat        = {T_FLOAT,0,"vbat"},
  .tempIcon    = {T_TEMP_ICON,(TempIcon*)TEMP_LOW,"p1"},
  .battIcon    = {T_BATT_ICON,(BattIcon*)BATT_FULL,"battIcon"}
};

static void updateValues(void)
{
// As you can see, now i'm typecasting them as I'm using them, which feels all kinds of wrong and also, as it turns out, doesn't even work!  surprise surprise....
    *(int*)screenData.temp.var++;
    *(int*)screenData.wattage.var++;
    *(int*)screenData.battPercent.var++;
    *(int*)screenData.rpmL.var++;
    *(int*)screenData.rpmR.var++;
    *(float*)screenData.vbat.var+=0.1;
   *(TempIcon*)screenData.tempIcon.var++;
    *(ScreenType*)screenData.battIcon.var++;
}
```

There's more code to make sure the enumerations don't grow beyond their bounds and so forth, but really, all I want to do is set this conceptual **object**, and send it to the the UART, with a function signature that looks like this:

`void ForChristsSakesJustSendTheDamnString(screenData * dat);`

I'm sure there's some better, idiomatic way to do this.  This is totally out of control and just *feels* wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: So... ¿Do you want to know a simplier way to hold different types in the same `struct` field?

Comment: I don't know what I want... that's why I'm asking.  I'm trying to be clear about what I'm trying to do and I know there's a more "scalable" way to code this in a more idiomatic C sort of way.... I'm asking how a more experienced C programmer would do this task